When we substitute $\tan(x/2) = t$, the length of the range of $x$ covered by this transformation is less than $2\pi$. Isn’t this a problem?
When $R(z, w)$ is a rational function, there is a method for computing
$$
\int R(\cos(x), \sin(x)) \, dx
$$
by substituting $ \tan(x/2) = t $.
Let $R(z, w) = z$.
Then we consider calculating:
$$
\int R(\cos(x), \sin(x)) \, dx = \int \cos(x) \, dx.
$$
By the definition of an indefinite integral, for any fixed $a \in \mathbb{R}$, this becomes the calculation of:
$$
\int_{a}^{x} \cos(t) \, dt.
$$
Assume $a = 0$.
$x$ varies over the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$.
However, when we substitute $\tan(x/2) = t$, the length of the range of $x$ covered by this transformation is less than $2\pi$.
But $x$ is supposed to range over $\mathbb{R}$.
Isn’t this a problem?

$${\def\ud{\mathrm{d}}}$$
you just be aware that, differential and indefinite integral are calculated in local, that's means, no matter what the function behavior far from some point $x_0$, both $f'(x_0)$ and $\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ near $x=x_0$ are determined in a suitable neibourhood of $x_0$, i.e. $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$. so, using substitute of $t=\tan(x/2)$ is always correct in a reasonable location of $x$. and connect the primitive function at the un-reasonable $x$ to fulfill the continuous property.
One example is the following calculating:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{4}+1}\ud x & =\int\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}}\ud x=\int\frac{\ud\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+2}\\
 & \int\frac{\ud t}{2+t^{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{\ud\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}}{1+\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}}\qquad \left(\text{set }t=x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{2}x}+C.
\end{align*}
The result appears the same problem near $x=0$, if you draw the graph of the result function, it appears

It shows the primitive function is not derivative at $x=0$, so there must not be the correct result, but you can shift the right part of the result up and set the result continous (and also derivative) at $x=0$ as
$$
\int\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{4}+1}\ud x=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\frac{x^{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}x}+C, & x<0,\\
\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}+C, & x=0,\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan\frac{x^{2}-1}{\sqrt{2}x}+C+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}, & x>0.
\end{cases}
$$
then the picture becomes

which is derivative at $x=0$.
The situation of yours is the same, but you need infinitely many shift to get the absolutely correct answer.

Larry Eppes, thank you very much for your nice example!

Doing substitution needs the new function is a monotonic function in $(a,x)$, and $ tan( \frac{x}{2} )$ is not monotony in $\mathbb{R}$, if you want to calculate $\int_{a}^{x} cos(t) dt$, notice that $cos(t)$is a periodic function, the integral equals to calculate$\int_{a}^{y} cos(t) dt$,$y=x\,mod\, 2\pi $, then you can use $ tan( \frac{x}{2} )$ to substitute t.

rosiness, thank you very much for your answer.
